# Stylus not allowing basic subtraction

Tags: stylus

Noticed an issue when using semantic grids stylus.

```
*width total-width * ((((gutter-width + column-width ) * x) - gutter-width) / _gridsystem-width)-correction
```

is processing to something along the lines(read different numbers)

```
  *width: 89.5833333333333% -correction;
```

So, I decided to performan an experiment. When running `stylus -i` I found subtraction there was also not operating (at all)

To verify I wrote this in my file

```
x=10
y=20
.something
    font-size y-x
```

which process to

```
.something {
  font-size: y-x;
}
```

Am I crazy? Did I interpret operators incorrectly with stylus?
Pending the results here I may open a ticket on github. I did find another person with an issue around percentages that highlights the `-` operator not functioning as expected. However, this doesn't seem related to my issue.

Tldr: basic math without units doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Immediate follower: 
I noticed my example is from an example with units and one without units. I added px to my x and y, but it didn't operate any differently.

Answer (score 6):

This is a known problem, dash `-` is counted as a part of a variable name, so when you write `-correction`, Stylus sees it as a variable `-correction`.

The obvious fix is to always use spaces around the minus: `- correction`, this way Stylus would always recognize the operator.

Comment: And watch out for this construction: `margin 0 -(N)`. Rather than compiling to `margin: 0 -Npx` (left and right margins), it compiles to `margin: -Npx` (all margins) because it evaluates `0 -(N)` as a single expression. The fix is to use `margin 0 (- N)`.