# Stylus. Negative variables

Tags: stylus

How can I use a negative variables in Stylus ?

I write mixin for a sprite:

```
sprite-medium(col,row)
  width = 40px
  height = 40px
  width: width
  height: height
  background: url('../img/medium-sprite.png') no-repeat
  background-position: -col*width -row*height
```

And I have an error. Of course I can write negative values in call of mixins, but it's not a perfect decision. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232729/stylus-not-allowing-basic-subtraction.

Answer (score 5):

Stylus is treating the `-` before `col` and `row` as part of the name - they need to be separated for that to work like `-(col * width)`, however you also need to avoid subtracting the two values that you want for background position. Here's a solution with a working background calculation and a bit simplified through the use of property lookups:

```
sprite-medium(col, row)
  width: 40px
  height: 40px
  background: url('../img/medium-sprite.png') no-repeat
  background-position: -(col * @width) -1 * (row * @height)
```

Hope this helps.